# How to create clickable hyperlink text in custom PHP code

Tags: php, string, wordpress, hyperlink

Please can I get some help with this - I have this part of code:

```
echo '<li><span>'.mg_wpml_string($type, $copt).':</span> '.$val.'</li>';
```

How to make this part

```
.$val.
```

clickable, so In fact how to put this part in a href so that users can click on this?

This is ordinary text ling but all values are entered as http addresses but I can not click on them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the HTML-code for a link (a href) in there...

```
echo '<li><span>'.mg_wpml_string($type, $copt).':</span> <a href="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps?

```
[...snip...]:</span><a href="somelinkhere">' . $val . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: I'm almost tempted to make the "Perhaps?" in bold, or `<h1>` myself ;-) +10000